# Change color ListView.Builder onPressed Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to change the color. if I choose index with value 'einamal'(true) it is will be green else (false) red.

```
List<String> _choices = <String>[ 'einmal','zweimal', 'dreimal', 'viemal' ];
List<bool> _hasBeenPressed = [true, false, false, false];

 Widget _buildChoice() {

    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _choices.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
          {
            return RaisedButton(
              child: new Text(_choices[index]),
              textColor: _hasBeenPressed[index] ? Colors.white : Colors.green,
              color: _hasBeenPressed[index] ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
              onPressed: () =>
              {
                setState(() {
                  if(_choices[index] == 'einmal') {
                    _hasBeenPressed[index] = !_hasBeenPressed[index];
                  }
                })
              },
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
              ),
            );
          }
      ),

    );
  }
```

[Screenshot of implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCM2W.png)

Comment: what problem are you facing. Can't really understand your problem from your question

Comment: if I select the index button 0 it will turn green, if I choose an index button other than 0 it will turn red. please check 'Screenshot of implementation'

Comment: where will the red color appear?

Answer (score 0):

You need another variable to store your actual answer, in your case it will be,

```
String answer = "einmal";
```

Now, you just need a `String` to store which option the user has selected and not a List, like this,

```
String selected = "";
```

Now, whenever user selects an option, update your `selected`, like this,

```
onPressed: () => {
  setState(() {
    selected = _choices[index];
  })
},
```

Now, use this to get correct color,

```
textColor: selected == _choices[index] ? Colors.white : Colors.green,
color: selected == _choices[index]
         ? (selected == answer ? Colors.green : Colors.red)
         : Colors.white,
```

Full code,

```
List<String> _choices = <String>['einmal', 'zweimal', 'dreimal', 'viemal'];
String answer = "einmal";

String selected = "";

Widget _buildChoice() {
  return Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _choices.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return RaisedButton(
          child: new Text(_choices[index]),
          textColor:
              selected == _choices[index] ? Colors.white : Colors.green,
          color: selected == _choices[index]
              ? (selected == answer ? Colors.green : Colors.red)
              : Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => {
            setState(() {
              selected = _choices[index];
            })
          },
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
        );
      }),
  );
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @TriWijiHastuti. Glad to have helped. Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you :)